# MarkLogic CoRB command

Tags: windows, xquery, marklogic, marklogic-corb

I have made a Query on MarkLogic that look up /customer.xml datasets and exports them on a local CSV file.
but the CoRB command doesnot seem to work and throws a error.

The CoRB command I executed below

```
java -cp ".\documents\marklogic-corb-2.3.2.jar;.\documents\marklogic-xcc-11.0.0.jar" \
> -DMODULE-DATABASE="Module" ^ 
> -DMODULE-ROOT="/" ^ 
> -DXCC-CONNECTION-URI="xcc://admin:admin@localhost:9100/" ^ 
> -DPROCESS-MODULE="/processQuery.xqy" ^ 
> -DURIS-MODULE="/uriQuery.xqy" ^ 
> -DTHREAD-COUNT=4 ^ 
> -DINSTALL="false" ^ 
> -DPROCESS-TASK="com.marklogic.developer.corb.ExportBatchtoFileTask" ^ 
> -DEXPORT-FILE-NAME="C:\work\test.csv" ^ 
com.marklogic.developer.corb.Manager
```

The error I got

```
Error initializing CORB For input string: "-DPROCESS-MODULE=/processQuery.xqy"
CoRB2 requires options to be specified through one or more of the following mechanisms:
1.) command-line parameters
2.) Java system properties ex: -DXCC-CONNECTION-URI=xcc://user:password@localhost:8202
3.) As properties file in the class path specified using -DOPTIONS-FILE=myjob.properties. Relative and full file system paths are also supported.
If specified in more than one place, a command line parameter takes precedence over a Java system property, which take precedence over a property from the OPTIONS-FILE properties file.
```

Comment: I'm not able to reproduce that error or message. I don't see where/how "For input string:" would be generated in an error message from an exception.

Comment: I used the command following and got a different error

java -cp "C:\marklogic-corb-2.3.2.jar";"C:\marklogic-xcc-11.0.0.jar" \
-DMODULE-DATABASE="Module" ^ 
-DMODULE-ROOT="/" ^ 
-DXCC-CONNECTION-URI="xcc://admin:admin@localhost:9100/" ^ 
-DPROCESS-MODULE="/processQuery.xqy" ^ 
-DURIS-MODULE="/uriQuery.xqy" ^ 
-DTHREAD-COUNT=4 ^ 
-DINSTALL="false" ^ 
-DPROCESS-TASK="com.marklogic.developer.corb.ExportBatchtoFileTask" ^ 
-DEXPORT-FILE-NAME="C:\test.csv" ^ 
com.marklogic.developer.corb.Manager

`Error initializing CORB com.marklogic.developer.corb.ExportBatchtoFileTask`

Comment: I cd'd to C:\ and copy and pasted the `marklogic-corb-2.3.2.jar`, `marklogic-xcc-11.0.0.jar` under C:\

Comment: I think "For input string: " comes from FormatNumberExceptions. Maybe the options aren't being sent in correctly, and that PROCESS-MODULE param is being included in the XCC-CONNECTION-URI and attempting to parse out the port number? You could probably simplify things and eliminate the problem of commandline and character escaping issues by putting all of the options in an options file and then just specify `-DOPTIONS-FILE=myOptions.properties`

Comment: The `ExportBatchToFileTask` has a capital T, not lowercase.

Comment: Thank you, the command worked!
dont know how I missed that mistake...